# Error in flutter run 'app:processDebugMAinManifest'. > : Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible...'

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

I cloned a repository of an appFlutter in production, I had several problems to be able to validate the flutter doctor, because the app was made in old versions.
But after a lot of research and attempts, getting it validated and approved; flutter, dart and java versions.

But when running Flutter run, I still get this error, and I can't understand what's wrong and how to solve it. Can you help? If you need any more information please let me know.

ERROR:

```
murillo@murillo-Inspiron-3442:~/Projects/brflor-app-cubagem/app_floresta$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi Note 8 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @47972fab

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             26.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Try checking the environments and versions again, as well as looking back at the grandle location, to try to understand the problem. But still without success...